# PHP script as form action: give server side effents

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-sent-events

I have a working PHP script running quite long (5 minutes at maximum). I want to inform to user after each step ("task 1 of 10 done").

I know, this is an old problem and I tried to solve it with server side events.

On the HTML side there is a form with my PHP script as the action:

```
<form action="my_script.php"><input type="submit" value="Submit!"/></form>
```

One requirement is, that the hole HTML page works (and calls my_script.php by submitting the form) without any scripting. The "live status reports" form the PHP script are intended to be an additional feature, but the page should completly work without it.

This is how I tried to do it: On the client side I added an `onsubmit()` event to the `form` tag calling a JavaScript function:

```
var source = new EventSource("my_script.php");
source.onmessage = function(event)
 {
  // display data in a div
 };
```

On the server side the PHP should send some messages to the calling HTML page (while doing its tasks) and after all tasks are done build a new HTML pages with all output.
I tried to do that like this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$output_stream = '';

// do something here. If a taks is done call send_to_output('something done');

function send_to_output($message)
{
 global $output_stream;
 echo "data: {$message}\n\n";
 flush();
 $output_stream .= $message;
}

header('Content-Type: text/html');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

echo "Everything is finished";
echo $output_stream;
```

But that doesn't work.

After some testing, I think that there are two problems:

1. The browser can't cope with the header 'Content-Type: text/event-stream' and offers to download the file.
2. The form action (`<form action="my_script.php">`) and the JavaScript event (`var source = new EventSource("my_script.php");`) seem each to open an own thread of the PHP script, so that there are **two** instances of this script running on the server.

How can I solve those problems?

Comment: If this is just a regular form submit, doesn't it halt execution in the browser while it's processing ?

Comment: Why inventing your own bicycle? I'd something like sockets.io instead

Comment: Please conform what should happen if the client does NOT support javascript

Comment: @adeneo: I don't get your point. My problem is: The script is executing well but it prints text only after it is completly finished. I want the user to see messages while the script is still running.

Comment: @user574632: If the client doesn't support JavaScript the user clicks on "submit", the PHP script runs and displays its results after some minutes. No status messages are displayed. And that is already working. So, no problem here.

Comment: @cis - The browser thread is busy when the form is submitting, that's why the messages doesn't show up until after the form is submitted.

Comment: Chuck PHP and use node js!

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this in the olden days, your form would submit directly to `my_script.php` which would direct the browser to load the content from that URL. `my_script.php` would first echo enough HTML for the browser to render the whole page, then flush its output buffers to ensure the client received it all. **Part of that page data would be a JS global function** -- something like `update_status`, that will receive the status events and update the UI. Then, on the same request, it would start the processing.

At various points during the processing, the script would echo something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">update_status('15%');</script>
```

and flush it to the client. The client would run these script tags as they came in, call the relevant function, and update the UI.

Today we have [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets). That is by far the best way to do it, providing your users have a capable browser.

You could also poll the server on a `setInterval`, but that would require splitting execution off into a different process (so as not to hang the browser or waste a web server worker) and adding an endpoint to the backend to expose the status of each process.

Comment: Ah, ok. I had a look at http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling/ and came to the conclusion that Server Side Events are the better solution for my problem because I thought WebSockets are a just over-complex for such a little issue. But will look into it.

Comment: WebSockets are a bit broad, I'll agree, but according to http://caniuse.com they have better support than EventSource -- especially in IE. One issue with EventSource is that it eats web server workers, if you use a process-based server like Apache. On even a large server, opening a few hundred of these connections can make your site unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this with standard ajax polling.
In this example i am just writing to a text file from the long running script, and loading it directly in the poll.

You would probably write to a db etc:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<form action="long.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="submit" value="submit "/>
</form>
<div id="progress">

</div>
<div id="result">

</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

    $(function(){
        var checkid ='';
        $('#myform').submit(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            var fm = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: fm.attr('action'),
                data: "",
                success: function(data){
                    clearInterval(checkid);
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });

            checkid = setInterval(function(){
                $.get('progress.txt', function(data){
                    $('#progress').html(data);
                });
            },1000);
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

//long.php
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
    sleep(2);
    file_put_contents('progress.txt', "done {$i} iterations", LOCK_EX);
}

echo 'all done';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of solutions or workarounds for problems like this. This is surely not the place to discuss which is general the best one. The intention of my question was just: How to solve that problem with Server Side Events?

Inspired by user574632 I've found now a quick and dirty solution:

My long running PHP scripts puts all messages into a file:

```
function send_to_output($message)
{
 global $output_stream; 
 $output_stream .= $message;
 file_put_contents('progress.txt',$output_stream);
}
```

Another PHP script sends all contents of this file to the client:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$file_content = file_get_contents('progress.txt');

echo "data: {$file_content}\n\n";
flush();

?>
```

In the HTML I simply had to change to file name of `var source = new EventSource("name.php")`.

This seems to work but it is no real smooth and nice looking solution.